# Get ajax response as comma separated

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to get ajax response as a comma separated values.

this is my ajax response

```
{
"data": [
   {
     "id": "xxxxxa"
   },
   {
     "id": "xxxxxxb"
   },
   {
     "id": "xxxxc"
   },
   {
     "id": "xxxxxd"
   }
]
}
```

result should be

```
xxxxa,xxxxb,xxxc,xxxxd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = {
"data": [
   {
     "id": "xxxxxa"
   },
   {
     "id": "xxxxxxb"
   },
   {
     "id": "xxxxc"
   },
   {
     "id": "xxxxxd"
   }
]
};

var arr=[];
$.each(data.data,function(i,v) {
   
   arr.push(v.id)
  });
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

1. Use `.each()` to get each value
2. Use `.push()` to combine them